# android create x509 certificate

Tags: android, ssl, x509, client-certificates

With java code, how can I create an x509 certificate that is later signed by an external private certificate authority?

- Android API 21
- Using the androidkeystore if possible (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore). This would be for security of the private key.
- The x509 certificate will be used as a client certificate for TLS communications
- Actual details of how the external certificate authority signs the certificate are not important here, just that it does.
- A certificate signing request will be forwarded to an external party to sign the certificate, then at a later point the signed certificate can be downloaded.

Somewhere the certificate signing request needs to be generated along with a public and private key. The private and public key need to be stored somehow until the signed certificate can be obtained, then the certificate needs to be linked to those private and public keys.

Answer (score 0):

just use some external authority, e.g. very common (because is free) is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

linked keystore is for keeping app-signing certificates, not network ones